# Asp Net get username

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Googled about this, but none of solutions solved this situation.

My web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true">
            </compilation>
      <authentication mode="Windows" />

    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My aspx page:

```
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string opl = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
        Response.Write("Name:" + opl);
    }
</script>
```

I'm getting an empty string, any ideas?I tried `Request.ServerVariables` but get an empty string for user also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get currently loggedin windows account from an asp.net page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184685/how-to-get-currently-loggedin-windows-account-from-an-asp-net-page)

Comment: I got it disabling anonymous access. =D. In the web.config I add this

 <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the name of the logged user you can use

var user = User.Identity.Name

or

var user = User.Identity.UserName

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var username = User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Context.User.Identity.Name.Tostring(), get the user name logged into the asp.net application not the windows account name.

Comment: using this I get empty

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is consult the HttpContext:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx

It will contain all of the information about the currently logged in user.