# How to get windows logged in user username using only Forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How to get windows logged in user username using only Forms authentication in asp.net mvc application after deploy on iis I try with many methods but no one don't work correctly like this

```
var userName1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
var userName2 = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate? [how to get currently loggedin windows account from an asp.net page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184685/how-to-get-currently-loggedin-windows-account-from-an-asp-net-page)

Comment: no I need only forms autentication I don't need windows autentication thank you for your answer

Comment: you cant - you must use Windows Authentication for that - the link provided by Izzy covers this.

Comment: but when I use windows autentication in my application administrator page everyone have access

Comment: then secure it by user or group - see the restrict access section of http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323176

Comment: No, not *everyone* has access. Windows auth automatically "logs in" the user. It's actually using impersonation. It treats as the user for the site whatever user is logged into Windows. So, you may not have to log in, per se, but you will only have the access that the Windows user has for the site.

Comment: can you show me how can i do that??