# Get User name in stead of DomainName\UserID in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication

i am using `User.Identity.Name` to get User Name.

But in stead of User Name I am getting DomainName\UserID.

I am using Windows Authentication.

Can anybody please suggest any way to get User Name instaed of UserID in windows authentication. C#.

Thank you....

Comment: similar post with solution you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184685/how-do-i-get-the-currently-loggedin-windows-account-from-an-asp-net-page

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for user display name. Here is way to get it :

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
var name = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
```

You need to add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll`

Answer (score -1):

```
logon_user = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].Substring(// you domain length here);
```

**e.g :
if Domain is "8" character long then,**

```
logon_user = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].Substring(8);
```